# fileinput.py deleting target file

Tags: python, unix, file-io

I am getting some strange behavior using the `fileinput` python module. If the file I am trying to alter does not have user read access, it gets deleted.

```
import fileinput

try:
    for line in fileinput.input('TEST', inplace=1):
        line = line.strip()
        if '/' in line:
            print "PATH: " + line
        else:
            print line
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

If I run this file, I get:

```
$ ls -l
--wxrwxrwx 1 myusername agqt3 0 Feb 25 11:02 TEST
$ python test.py
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'TEST.bak'
$ ls -l
total 0
```

The file gets deleted. The same thing occurs with every other combination of permission bits that do not include the user `r`. I have reproduced this in `bash`, `csh` and `ksh`.

Comment: The permission denied error is occurring because the "w" permission on the directory containing TEST is missing maybe?

Comment: @Cthulhu: Doesn't seem to be the case. Also, I can confirm that it is still happening even if I create a new directory in `/tmp` and set `/tmp/newDir` to `777` and run everything inside this new directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in `fileinput`.  Suggest you open an issue about it on the [Python Bug Tracker](http://bugs.python.org)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using `inplace=1`, so yes the file is expected to be overwritten.
When this is done a `.bak` file is created, and the initial file name overwritten.

However, you do *not* have permissions to read the inital file (*but can write*), so when the backup is created it is empty (or fails), and the original overwritten.

From the *inplace* documentation:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput

> **Optional in-place filtering**: if the keyword argument *inplace=1* is
>   passed to fileinput.input() or to the FileInput constructor, the file
>   is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input
>   file (if a file of the same name as the backup file already exists, it
>   will be replaced silently). This makes it possible to write a filter
>   that rewrites its input file in place. If the backup parameter is
>   given (typically as backup='.'), it specifies the
>   extension for the backup file, and the backup file remains around; by
>   default, the extension is '.bak' and it is deleted when the output
>   file is closed. In-place filtering is disabled when standard input is
>   read.

Comment: Silently losing a file's content isn't very nice behavior.  `fileinput` should not let you do that.

Comment: programming is not for the weak at heart :P

Comment: True but while Python is for consenting adults, it is not totally heartless.

Comment: Any workaround exists for the .bak file to be deleted (besides not using the backupfile parameter in the first place)?